# How to create watermark underlined text using ffmpeg

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

I am trying to create a watermark with underlined text, but I am not able to find drawtext filter for underlined text.

Here is my command:

```
ffmpeg -i ./public/uploads/videos/1577703125107.mp4 -vf "[in]drawtext=fontfile= ./public/fonts/Arial/arial.ttf: text=my watermark text: fontcolor=#000000: fontsize=20: x=23:y=68 [out]" ./public/uploads/videos/1577703128790.mp4
```

How can I underline text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## drawbox filter

If you want to use the drawtext filter you would have to draw the line separately with [drawbox](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawbox):

[image]

```
ffmpeg input.mpt -filter_complex "drawtext=text='my watermark text':fontsize=20:fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/TTF/VeraMono.ttf:x=23:y=68,drawbox=w=205:h=2:x=23:y=85:t=fill" output.mp4
```

This my be easiest if you use a monospaced font.

## subtitles filter

A possibly simpler, and better looking, alternative method is to use the [subtitles](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles) filter:

[image]

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "subtitles=underline.srt:force_style='Alignment=3,Fontsize=22'" output.mp4
```

Contents of `underline.srt`:

```
1
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:05,000
<u>my watermark text</u>
```

If you don't want to use keypad position Alignment tag you can use ASS file instead of SRT with `\pos` tag for more accurate placement. See [ASS tags](http://docs.aegisub.org/3.2/ASS_Tags/).

Comment: Can you please tell me how can we draw underline using drawtext with drawbox or drawgrid.

Comment: @ApoorvSrivastava Added.

Comment: Yea its working with drawbox=w=205:h=2:x=23:y=85:t=fill but when i am trying for multiple lines , its creating issue.

Comment: @ApoorvSrivastava You'll have to create multiple drawbox lines.